# jQuery Lightbox open multiple images from one link

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to have Lightbox open a gallery of images from clicking on one thumbnail. When you click on it, you should then be able to scroll through a couple of images. Here is my site:  http://eta.terrellplace.com/terrell.php

I tried to follow this:

[How to make a jquery lightbox open multiple images from one link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428401/how-to-make-a-jquery-lightbox-open-multiple-images-from-one-link)

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="fit">
    <div id='gallery'>
        <a href="images/plans/LEVEL 6[23].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"><img src="images/plans/smallsuites-thumb.jpg" alt="" /></a>
        <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_3[25].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
        <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_2-_TECH[25].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
        <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_2_-_OFFICE[18].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
        <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_2_-_OFFICE[18].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gallery a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true});
    $('#gallery a:gt(0)').hide();
});
```

Can someone tell me what I seem to be missing here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give a `rel=""` attribute.

```html
<a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL 3[25].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
<a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL 2- TECH[25].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
<a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL 2 - OFFICE[18].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
<a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL 2 - OFFICE[18].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>
```

It's something strange to see file names having spaces in them. Don't use file names with spaces, when you are hosting it in the server.

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for the quick response.  I made your suggested changes, but I still can't scroll between images.  Here's how the code looks now:         
 <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_3[25].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>

 <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_2-_TECH[25].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>

 <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_2_-_OFFICE[18].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>

 <a rel="gallery" href="images/plans/LEVEL_2_-_OFFICE[18].jpg" title="" class="lightbox"></a>

          </div>
          </div>

Comment: I'm sorry Praveen.  It won't let me put returns in.

Comment: Hence why you update your code with ammendments in the question, not in comments.

Comment: @WilliamHodge Please edit your original question (click on the edit link) and update.

Comment: Praveen, I changed the code in the original post to how it looks now.  Thanks for help, I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: @WilliamHodge I just saw your code, and I couldn't find any `rel="gallery"` or similar attributes.

Comment: @Praveenkumar - Thanks for you help.  I just needed to add rel="gallery" on the first image.  I knew it had to be something simple that I over looked.  I appreciate the time you took to help me.